# Given an interval, Find all intervals In a list of Intervals

Tags: algorithm, intervals, segment-tree, interval-tree

Let say I have a list of ranges like this

`[[1,3], [2,5], [4,6], [8,10], [12,15], [13,17]]`

Now I want to find a range say `[3,11]` falls in. My algorithm should give me all the ranges this range falls to. For example the output for this should be

`Output - [1,3], [2,5], [4,6], [8,10]`

How do i go about solving this?

PS: I know segment tree might be helpful. Where I can build the tree to store interval and query a Point lying inside interval, but how to get all intervals given a interval.

Comment: From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree we have "Specifically, it allows one to efficiently find all intervals that overlap with any given interval or point"

Comment: If this is a one-off task given a list of ranges, you simply brute-force through the list. If you need to query often on the same data, you build a tree. If the data changes often but you query rarely, you might find another structure more useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interval Tree is definitely the data structure you need. I faced the same problem and in order to improve performances I used **Augmented Interval Tree** where every node includes, in addition to the bounds of the range, also the information related to **the maximum value of the subtree of the node**.

You can find here an in depth explanation and a Java implementation: [Data Structures: Augmented Interval Tree to search for intervals overlapping](http://www.davismol.net/2016/02/07/data-structures-augmented-interval-tree-to-search-for-interval-overlapping/)